# Custom Control Event Handler Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, custom-controls, designer

All, I have the a custom user control which is invoked using a singleton pattern. This control can be shown or hidden and to update the UI (to provide a show/hide control option) I set up an event handler in the controls constructor.

```
this.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(ResultsControl_VisibleChanged);
```

and the event handler is

```
void ResultsControl_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get reference to Show/Hide button.
    var showHideResults = ((SqlEditorForm)this.ParentForm).ShowHideResultsButton;
    if (instance != null)
        showHideResults.Enabled = true;

    // Change the status.
    showHideResults.Text = this.Visible ? 
        "&Hide Query Results" : 
        "&Show Query Results";
    showHideResults.Image = this.Visible ?
        Properties.Resources.HideResultsVS201224 :
        Properties.Resources.ShowResultsVS201224;
}
```

The problem is with the way I am getting the reference to the `ShowHideResultsButton`. I am getting the following error thrown from the designer...

[image: DesignerError]

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. I seem to have solved this by moving the*

```
this.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(ResultsControl_VisibleChanged);
```

*from the constructor to the controls Load event. So the question now becomes: is this a valid fix?*

Comment: Are you sure that parent form of the ResultsControl is the SqlEditorForm?

Comment: Yes. This is the main form of the application and there are only two forms in the entire app.

Comment: And the ResultsControl is on on it or on the other form?

Comment: It is on the form that I reference `SqlEditorForm`. I belive it is added dynamically at runtime so your answer below makes sense. However, it does not make sense that it now works when wired up in the Load event.

Comment: Form_Load event is executed after the form constructor, hence after the InitializeComponent call which will set the ParentForm property to the apropriate instance of the SqlEditorForm.

Comment: This has not worked as I had thought. I now get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment when you are designing your `UserControl` you don't have a reference to the `SqlEditorForm`. It's `ParentForm` property will become `SqlEditorForm` only when you put your `ResultsControl` on the `SqlEditorForm` either using designer or by code. Until then IDE only knows that it is of type Form. Why don't you implement your `ResultsControl_VisibleChanged` event handler within `SqlEditorForm`?

Comment: +1 Tahnks for your answer. In the end I have set up the viable changed event handler using the desiger. I will now test if this works. Thanks for your time here...